# How to execute a MySQL function in a Knex query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I have a `BINARY` field in my table which I usually grab like this:

```
SELECT HEX(users.id) AS id FROM users WHERE username = ?
```

I recently started using Knex because I need to be able to dynamically generate `WHERE` clauses from objects. Here's what I tried:

```
knex('users').select('HEX(users.id) AS id)').where(filter);
```

Here's the query it generates:

```
select `HEX(users`.`id)` as `id` ....
```

And then I tried this:

```
knex('users').select('HEX(`users`.`id`) AS id').where(filter);
```

And it comes up with this:

````
select `HEX(``users```.```id``)` as `id` ....
````

How do I execute `HEX()` without it being mistaken for a column name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With knex letting to do quoting of identifiers it would look like this:

```
knex('users').select(knex.raw('HEX(??) AS id', ['users.id'])).where(filter);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution. I have to use `raw()` function. So my query builder will look like this:

```
knex('users').select(knex.raw('HEX(`users`.`id`) AS id')).where(filter);
```

Comment: i hate using raw. Whats the query builder for?